# Bootstrap rows & col responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using bootstrap's grid, is it possible to build something responsive like this?

[image: I've drawn it out.]

This is what I attempted at so far.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default profile_header">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <% for user in @users %>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-3">
                    <%= image_tag(user.avatar.url(:medium), :class => "avatar_profile") %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-9">
                    <h2 class="profile_name"><%= user.name %></h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            <h2 class="profile_bio"><%= user.bio%></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for mobile, I want the purple column to pop out and displayed under. The content is too crunched up right now, and breaking it into its own full width box would be much better. Is it possible though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't ask how cells should look for `sm` viewport (from 768px till 991px) It should look like for `md` or like for `xs`?

Here is a snippet for `md` and `xs` viewports

```css
.purple {
    background: purple;
}
.orange {
    background: orange;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
div[class^="col-"]{
    height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    div.orange {
        height: 200px !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 orange">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-7 green">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 purple">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Banzay! Sorry about forgetting the sm. It should look like the md, and I have included it in my new code so no worries. Thanks again.